# Get tables and views (and their columns) involved in a given procedure or a function in a database - Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to list all the columns, tables, views in a given procedure or a function in a database.

Example:
[image]

value1 and value2 being the columns.

**What have I tried?**

I have tried these two commands

`SHOW USER FUNCTIONS IN DATABASE {db_name};` and `SHOW PROCEDURES IN DATABASE {db_name};`

they give what procedures and functions are there and their definitions but not the tables,views and columns involved.

Is there a way to get the desired result(above table)?

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake does not provide this information for procedures and functions yet. There is a dependency function that can be used for "views":

GET_OBJECT_REFERENCES: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/get_object_references.html